# converting wav -> mp3 -> wav creates static noise

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pyaudio, pydub

I'm trying to convert my microphone audio into mp3 files and later save them on disk so I can record and save audio tracks.

But to play it back wit `pyaudio` I need to convert it into `wav` format.
It's originally recorded in `wav` and I'm trying to do `wav -> mp3 -> wav`.

And I've put together the smallest possible debug version of my code, and it looks like the following:

```
import pyaudio
from array import array
from struct import pack
from sys import byteorder
from io import BytesIO
from pydub import AudioSegment

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream_mic = p.open(rate=11000,
                        format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=1,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=500)

stream_out = p.open(rate=11000,
                        format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=1,
                        output=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=500)

def is_odd(a):
    return bool(a - ((a>>1)<<1))

def wav_obj(raw_data):
    wavHandle = AudioSegment(data=raw_data, sample_width=2, frame_rate=11000, channels=1)
    return wavHandle

def wavToMp3(audioFrame):
    mp3 = BytesIO()
    file_handle = audioFrame.export(mp3, format="mp3")
    mp3.seek(0)
    data = mp3.read()
    ## == Data needs to be multiple of (sample_width * channels)
    ##    Easiest way is to strip of a trailing data, 
    while is_odd(len(data)):
        data = data[:-1]
    return AudioSegment(data=data, sample_width=2, frame_rate=11000, channels=1)

def mp3ToWav(audioFrame):
    #remasteredAudioFrame = audioFrame.set_frame_rate(11000)
    wav = BytesIO()
    file_handle = audioFrame.export(wav, format="wav")
    wav.seek(0)
    return AudioSegment(data=wav.read(), sample_width=2, frame_rate=11000, channels=1)

while 1:
    snd_data = array('h', stream_mic.read(500))
    if byteorder == 'big':
        snd_data.byteswap()

    frame = array('h')
    frame.extend(snd_data)

    wav = wav_obj(frame)

    ## == convert from .wav -> .mp3 -> .wav
    ##    just to see the loss of audio.
    mp3 = wavToMp3(wav)
    wav = mp3ToWav(mp3)

    stream_out.write(wav.raw_data)

stream_out.stop_stream()
stream_mic.stop_stream()
stream_out.close()
stream_mic.close()
p.terminate()
```

This creates a horrible static, it's a 100% loss of audio some how.
At first I thought it was the clipping of `data[:-1]` but that at least to me doesn't appear to be the problem.

secondly I thought the frame rate might be off, so I tried doing `set_frame_rate(11000)` but that didn't work either.

commenting out these two lines:

```
mp3 = wavToMp3(wav)
wav = mp3ToWav(mp3)
```

Makes the playback sound "beautiful". There's no data loss and the quality is just as I've defined it to be.

I can't for the love of me figure out where I'm mixing up the data compression.
**Note:** I want to do this in-memory if possible because I'll later on work with the data in order to try and create effects etc.

### Progress

As @Anthon pointed out, I should isolate the conversions one by one and see which of the two fail. And I did this by saving the `wav -> mp3` to disk.

```
started = time()
sound = AudioSegment(data=b'', sample_width=2, frame_rate=11000, channels=1)
while 1:
    snd_data = array('h', stream_mic.read(500))
    if byteorder == 'big':
        snd_data.byteswap()

    frame = array('h')
    frame.extend(snd_data)

    wav = wav_obj(frame)

    ## == convert from .wav -> .mp3 -> .wav
    ##    just to see the loss of audio.
    mp3 = wavToMp3(wav)
    sound = sound + mp3
    #wav = mp3ToWav(mp3)

    #stream_out.write(mp3.raw_data)
    if time() - started > 1.5:
        break

print(sound.raw_data)
with open('test.mp3', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(sound.raw_data)
```

I then slammed `test.mp3` into audacity to see what the wave formed looked like.
Sure enough it looks like it's the `.mp3` conversion that's wonky.

It looks to the naked eye as if the audio frames were getting dragged out and distorted indivudually. The sound should be roughly 1.5 seconds long in total, but looking at the wave form, there's pauses and delays in each frame added by the compressor:

[image]

So i bumped up the value `frames_per_buffer=500` to `2000` on all instances where this value was used:

```
stream_mic = p.open(frames_per_buffer=5000, ...)
stream_out = p.open(frames_per_buffer=5000, ...)
stream_mic.read(5000)
```

Any value above my `1.5 seconds` should be a good enough value.
Sure enough, the wave form looks completely different:

[image]

What appears to be working is the following:

```
wav = wav_obj(frame)
sound = sound + wav

sound.export("test.mp3",
              format="mp3",
              bitrate="11k",
              tags={"album": "test", "artist": "Not Ariana Grande"})
```

So some how, the `wav frame -> mp3 frame -> combine several mp3 frames` doesn't work.
But doing `wav frame -> combine several wav frames -> export to mp3` works.

This is where I'm stuck again.
Obviously the `mp3` conversion is wonky, and it some how adds distortion pitches across the wave form per segment.
My hope is that someone of you here on SO have worked with `pydub` and especially mp3 conversion, because I'm quite lost.

Here's the mp3:s gathered:

- https://hvornum.se/500.mp3
- https://hvornum.se/5000.mp3

Comment: I have no idea what mp3 encoder the `.export` uses and/or if you can set its quality. I would try to do an external conversion first (with e.g. `lame` save wav>lame>read mp3) to pinpoint that its the encoding (likely) and not the decoding and then see how to improve the quality of the culprit.

Comment: @Anthon Solid tip! I'll try with an external encoder/decoder. `pyaudio` uses either `libav` or `ffmpeg`, in that order. I've tried both and the results are the same.

Comment: I don't think you can convert to MP3 in chunks and then recombine - most (maybe all?) MP3 encoders add some silence to the beginning or end of the converted audio. If you want to compress the data to save bandwidth, try piping through lame or just gripping the wave data